# DEVPATH and MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, gac

I found posts mentioning issues with DEVPATH and webapps and I think MVC falls under this same band-wagon.

On my local PC; in one instance I need to be able to design and test our library of dlls; on another, I need to use these dlls, in various websites. Due to the number of sites we handle, we are looking at storing the dlls in the GAC in an attempt to avoid duplication.

When I want to work on the library I need to remove all the dlls from the GAC and then re-install them again once I have finished my development.

I have everything set as defined in various sources to make DEVPATH work, but it isnt working for me in my MVC project.

Is it possible to have dlls installed in the GAC, but run an MVC project that uses the DEVPATH copy.

I'm not having a lot of luck finding anything on the subject, but I am hoping it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got a work around, it was quite obvious now I have done it.

It is a bit of work, but it does mean you can debug a website.

Also, it isn't using DEVPATH still, but it works so I am happy.

The main assumption I made was that the GAC always wins, even if you physically copy the dll to the bin the GAC will find the file first and use that reference.

So, the way I have found to work with local files (especially when I want to be debugging a website), is to change the assembly version number of the projects I reference to a new number. As this version doesn’t exist in the GAC, the Visual Studio webserver(cassini?) and iis web servers will use the local dlls. So any breakpoints I had added to my services etc. will then be picked up.